# Gauss-Weingarten relations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

In the 3.4 theorem, $F:R^n\supset U \rightarrow F(U)\subset M\subset R^{n+1}$ is a local represent of Riemannian manifold $M$. $g_{ij}$ is Riemannian metric , and $h_{ij}$ is second fundamental form. $\nu$ is outward normal vector. Then, how to show the red line from the Weingarten equation ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math646/huisken.convexflow.pdf

Comment: @jimbo   Yes, it is this paper. Do you know how to get the red line ?

Comment: @jimbo   could you tell me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A surfaces in the euclidean space the Gauss equations and the Weingarten equations
are

$$X_{uu} = \Gamma^1
_{1 1}X_u + \Gamma^2
_{
1 1}X_v + eN,
$$
$$X_{uv} =\Gamma^1_{1 2}X_u + \Gamma^2_{
1 2}X_v + fN,
$$
$$X_{vu} =\Gamma^1_{2 1}X_u + \Gamma^2
_{
2 1}X_v + fN,
$$
$$X_{vv }=\Gamma^1_{2 2}X_u + \Gamma^2_{
2 2}X_v + gN,$$
$$N_u = aX_u + cX_v,$$
$$N_v = bX_u + dX_v$$

A case general is your question.

Answer (score 5):

Let  $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial x_{k}} = X_k$, and

$$ \nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Gamma^k_{ij} X_k.$$
Because tangential component of Euclidean directional derivative is the Riemannian connection on the surface we have that
$$\frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{ x_{i}}\partial{x_{j}}}=D_{X_{i}} X_{j} = \nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j} + \alpha \nu. $$
Now, if we multiply(  inner product ) both sides of the last equation by $\nu$, we get
$$<D_{X_{i}} X_{j},\nu> = <\nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j},\nu> + <\alpha \nu,\nu>= \alpha;$$
(note that $\nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j} \perp \nu, $ so $<\nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j},\nu>=0$).
Thus $\alpha= -h_{ij}$. Therefore
$$\frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{ x_{i}}\partial{x_{j}}} = \nabla_{X_{i}} X_{j}  -h_{ij}\nu = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Gamma^k_{ij} X_k  -h_{ij}\nu.$$
Since $\left< \nu , X_k  \right>= 0$, we infer from compatibility of metric with respect to the connection that
$\left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial{ x_{j}} }, X_k  \right>+ \left<\nu, \frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{ x_{k}}\partial{x_{j}}} \right>=0$. Thus
$$\left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial{ x_{j}} }, X_k  \right>= h_{jk}.$$
Similarly, we infer from $\left< \nu, \nu \right> = 1$ and compatibility of metric with respect to connection that $\left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}, \nu \right> =0 $. Thus $ \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}$ is in the tangent space. So there are scalars  $\alpha_i $ such that
$$ \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}} = \sum\limits_{l=1}^n \alpha^j_{l} X_i.$$

We have that
$$ h_{jk}= \left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}  , X_k \right> = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha^j_{i} \left<  X_i,  X_k \right>=  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha^j_{i} g_{ik}= (\alpha^j_{1},..., \alpha^j_{n})(g_{1k},..., g_{nk})^T.$$
If we multiply both sides by $(g^{k1},..., g^{kn})$, we get
$$(\alpha^j_{1},..., \alpha^j_{n})= h_{jk}(g^{k1},..., g^{kn}). $$
Thus
$$\alpha^j_{l} =h_{jk}g^{kl} .$$
Now, consider

$$Z=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n  \sum\limits_{l=1}^n h_{jk}g^{kl} X_l.$$

We claim that  $ \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}= Z$. To see this, we multiply $Z$ by $X_i$, we will have

$$\left< Z, X_i \right> =\left< \sum\limits_{k=1}^n  \sum\limits_{l=1}^n h_{jk}g^{kl} X_l, X_i \right> =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n  \sum\limits_{l=1}^n h_{jk}g^{kl} g_{li} = h_{ji}= \left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}  , X_i \right>.$$

Since $X_i$ is a basis for the tangent space, $Z$ is uniquely determined by the values of $ \left< Z, X_i \right>$. Also, we got $\left< Z, X_i \right>= \left< \frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}}  , X_i \right>$ for each $i$,
thus $\frac{\partial{\nu}}{\partial x_{j}} =Z.$
Concluding the proof.

Comment: Hello, may I ask you a question, please? In which book did you see the notation $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial x_{k}}$? It seems to denote a vector field. Is there a textbook that includes the notation? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Boar Hi, sorry for the late reply. Here $F$
 is a parametrization and the notation is simply $dF(e_k)=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial x_{k}} = X_k$
, where $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$
 is  the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$. I have seen it in references for curvature flows. As an example see second chapter of [Xi-Ping_Zhu]_Lectures_on_Mean_Curvature_Flows

Comment: Thank you and happy new year.

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you! I hope this new year has been treating you well so far. Wishing you continued happiness throughout the year